# NIX - go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off;

Tags: go, unix, nix

I'm trying to download and build a project written in golang using nix

My nix file:

```
buildGoPackage {      
  name = "site";     
  goPackagePath = "git@github.com:username/rep.git";    
  src = fetchGit{      
       url = "git@github.com:username/rep.git";     
  }; 
}
```

run:

```
nix build -f test3.nix
```

error log:

```
last 8 log lines:        
 > unpacking sources       
 > unpacking source archive /nix/store/l1gsllgg693s46sk7b7qiwbnjysnbbz6-source        
 > source root is source        
 > patching sources        
 > configuring       
 > building        
 > Building subPackage git@github.com:user/rep.git        
 > go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off; see 'go help modules'
```

Comment: Turn modules on by GO111MODULE=on

Comment: does this need to be done in a nix file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using `buildGoModule` instead of `buildGoPackage`, as buildGoPackage is deprecated, according to [the nixpkgs documentation for go](https://ryantm.github.io/nixpkgs/languages-frameworks/go/).

Additionally, `buildGoModule` doesn't seem to set `GO111MODULE=off`.